# Cannot rename backup of Desktop folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I made a backup of the Desktop folder of user X (i.e. C:\Users\X\Desktop) onto an external drive (P:\Users\X\Desktop), then I renamed it "P:\Users\X\Desktop.20211026" because I intend to keep several backups over time.

Windows Explorer shows "P:\Users\X\Desktop.20211026" as expected, but other programs show "P:\Users\X\Desktop". This is from Windows CMD:

```
Directory of P:\Users\X
2021-10-26  13:10    <DIR>          .
2021-10-26  13:10    <DIR>          ..
2021-10-30  17:26    <DIR>          Desktop
```

I see "P:\Users\X\Desktop" in Windows CMD, in PowerShell, in the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows and in a Python program. Every program - except Windows Explorer - shows "P:\Users\X\Desktop". Windows Explorer shows "P:\Users\X\Desktop.20211026" in the address bar, but "P:\Users\X\Desktop" if I click into the address bar.

What is going on? Is "Desktop" such an important folder in Windows that it cannot be renamed, even when it is a copy sitting on some random external drive? If so, why does Windows Explorer pretend to allow me to change its name, then show a mix of the old name and new name?

Using Windows 10, latest patches.

Comment: I gave up fighting against Windows and I decided to store the backups in a "P:\Users\X\yyyyMMdd\Desktop" structure instead. This works as expected.

Comment: There is a desktop.ini file in the folder with the language translation of Desktop (in English it is desktop). For special folders (ie with Read Only or System set). You were renaming the display name not the foldername. **Delete the desktop.ini** which is hidden (so `del P:\Users\X\Desktop\desktop.ini`).

Comment: You also need to be careful when moving special folders. If you move a folder Windows will update the registry to the new location. Both this and desktop.inis **only** apply to *Explorer*. They have no meaning to the rest of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop is a very important folder. Many documents, email and other data goes there.

It is owned by the user and non-user cannot change it without taking complete ownership. Since it is just a backup, that is not a good idea.

Make holding folders well identified and copy the Desktop backups into the holding folders. Holding folders are just ordinary folders and can include a date that makes sense to you: yyyymmmdd or sometimes just yyyymmm

I think this is the best approach overall. I use variations of this on my machines.